# TypeError: agg() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, dask-dataframe

Im working on dask groupby and I'm facing some issues here

i have defined my custom_max it works just fine without dask.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from something import custom_max
df.head()
              Date      Time          productID  some_id     some_name   ... 
133192  26/10/2015  22:50:57  16037492655230761375561  12345   rahul     ...
133186  26/10/2015  22:50:48  16037492655330761377104  12345   rahul     ...
27323   26/10/2015  22:50:36  16037483834140761373004  3456    rajesh    ...
27322   26/10/2014  22:50:33  16037483834150761373390  3564    suresh    ...
133191  26/10/2014  22:50:33  16037492655330761377107  3456    rajesh    ...
new_grouped = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10).groupby(["some_id"])
new_grouped
agg_meta = 
{'some_name': NamedAgg(column='some_name', aggfunc=<function custom_max at 0x7fe6f5c16e18>)}
<dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fe6f5441978>
agg_df = new_grouped.agg(**agg_meta).compute()
TypeError: agg() got an unexpected keyword argument 'some_name'
```

can any one please guide me on what mistake im doing and

I'm using pandas 0.25.3 and dask 2.9.0

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the whole dictionary in `agg` method without the **.

```py
agg_df = new_grouped.agg(agg_meta).compute()
```